# Xcode: Scheme scripts vs Target scripts

Tags: ios, macos, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I tried to run a script at building time for one of my xcode projects.

way 1) I added a pre-action (run script) to my current scheme for "Build". It did not work, actually, it did not run at all.
way 2) Then I added the same script to the target ( "target", build phases seciton ). It ran as expected.

Questions:
1) why the pre-action script did not run? (I tried with an "email action", it did worked)
2) what is the difference between setting the script in the "scheme" vs "in build phases"? My guess is that, for the last one It always will run (at build time), without caring about the current scheme, is that all the difference?

Funny fact: Xcode crashes when I edit the Build > pre-action section

I made sure the right scheme is selected.

Xcode Version 4.4.1 (4F1003)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? My pre-action scripts don't run either (also Xcode 4.4.1).

Comment: Xcode 4.5.2 (4G2008a)... sometimes pre-action script works, sometimes no :(

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065905/scheme-script-vs-build-phase-script